# Mule esb Unable to deserialize message

Tags: mule

We have a Mule project, which works as follows:

We read of the database for a Id value, we use it to read from the database multiple records, to process one by one using a 'foreach'.

Everything works fine, but there are some records that give the following error when arriving at new flow.

> INFO  2014-07-11 10:00:45,584 [[tcol_act_es_insert].adapter_act_es_insert.stage1.45] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: --TRACE Id Lote en proceso: 44197277
>   INFO  2014-07-11 10:00:45,584 [[tcol_act_es_insert].adapter_act_es_insert.stage1.48] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: --TRACE Id Lote en proceso: 44197278
>   INFO  2014-07-11 10:00:45,584 [[tcol_act_es_insert].adapter_act_es_insert.stage1.47] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: --TRACE Id Lote en proceso: 44197279
>   WARN  2014-07-11 10:00:45,585 [[tcol_act_es_insert].adapter_act_es_insert.stage1.01] org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueSession: Unable to deserialize message
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at org.mule.util.store.DeserializationPostInitialisable$Implementation$1.run(DeserializationPostInitialisable.java:48)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at org.mule.util.store.DeserializationPostInitialisable$Implementation.init(DeserializationPostInitialisable.java:40)
>     at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueSession$QueueImpl.postProcessIfNeeded(TransactionalQueueSession.java:242)
>     at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueSession$QueueImpl.poll(TransactionalQueueSession.java:161)
>     at org.mule.processor.SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.dequeue(SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:130)
>     at org.mule.processor.SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.run(SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:205)
>     at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>   Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>     at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(AbstractHashedMap.java:1113)
>     at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap$KeySetIterator.next(AbstractHashedMap.java:938)
>     at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.setMessage(DefaultMuleEvent.java:968)
>     at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.initAfterDeserialisation(DefaultMuleEvent.java:732)
>     ... 14 more

Then I take the record that caused the error, **if this record is processed a second time will be processed correctly.**

This is my code mule...

```
   <flow name="tcol_act_es_insert" doc:name="tcol_act_es_insert" initialState="started"> 
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="select_counter_id" queryTimeout="10" pollingFrequency="30000" connector-ref="Dabase_otros_dev_insert" doc:name="InputDatabase_Counter"> 
        <jdbc-ee:query key="select_counter_id" value="select * from todocoleccion.dbo.config where field='act_es_last_id'"></jdbc-ee:query>  
    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>  
    <set-variable variableName="InputRowsetCounter" value="#[payload]" doc:name="InputRowsetCounter"></set-variable>

    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="ReloadLotes" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_dev_insert" doc:name="ReloadLotes"> 
        <jdbc-ee:query key="ReloadLotes" value="select TOP 50 CONVERT(varchar(50), l.Ultima_Modificacion, 127)+'Z' as ultima_modificacion, l.Id_Lote as id_lote, 
...
       where Id_Lote&gt;#[InputRowsetCounter.value] and l.Id_Seccion=s.Id_Seccion order by id_lote;"></jdbc-ee:query>  
    </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>  
    <set-variable variableName="InputRowsetLotes" value="#[payload]" doc:name="InputRowsetLotes"></set-variable>
    <expression-filter expression="#[!payload.isEmpty()]" doc:name="sinLotes"></expression-filter>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="update_counter_config" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_todocoleccion_dev_insert" doc:name="Update_Counter"> 
        <jdbc-ee:query key="update_counter_config" value="update todocoleccion.dbo.config set value=#[InputRowsetLotes[InputRowsetLotes.size()-1].id_lote] where field='act_es_last_id'"></jdbc-ee:query>  
    </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>  
    <foreach collection="InputRowsetLotes" counterVariableName="counterLotes" rootMessageVariableName="rootMessageLotes" doc:name="For Each Lote"> 
        <flow-ref name="adapter_act_es_insert" doc:name="Flow Reference Dispatcher"></flow-ref>  
    </foreach>  
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy"> 
        <flow-ref name="error_handler_act_es_insert" doc:name="Ref Error Handler"></flow-ref>  
    </catch-exception-strategy>  
</flow>
<flow name="adapter_act_es_insert" doc:name="adapter_act_es_insert"> 
    <choice doc:name="Choice"> 
        <when expression="!payload.isEmpty()"> 
            <logger message="--TRACE Id Lote en proceso: #[payload.id_lote]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
```

We are using mule-standalone-3.5.0-M4.tar.gz on Ubuntu Server 64 bits.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Try using 3.5.0, M4 is a early access release not intended for production deployment.

Comment: Perfect, Ale! You're right. We changed to 3.5.0 and there are no errors. Muchas gracias.